# C++ variable header scope

Tags: c++, scope, extern

I have a number of *templatic* and *inline* functions defined in an *header* file (let's call it `head.h`). Currently, these functions use some global variables declared with `extern` in the same header and defined somewhere in one *.cpp*.

Everything works fine, but I would limit global variables scope only to the header where they are defined.

In other words every other *.h* or *.cpp* that includes my *head.h* wouldn't be able to see such globals.

Any way to achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If multiple includers need to use the functions which in turn need to access the same global variable, how do you want to prevent the includers from seeing and using the global variable?

Comment: @WernerHenze because i don't want variable pollution. these variables must be used only in that header. if functions weren't inline i would define my globals in cpp as static, limiting their scope to that cpp

Comment: or anonymous namespace as someone suggested below

Comment: I see but if several functions in the header use these variables at the same time, I would probably create a class around it. If possible, the variables could also be passed from one function to another. I think, a really nice solution depends a lot on your actual application

Comment: @IceFire I agree and I know benefits of well written and scalable code. My question here is mainly for interest. To be honest I don't know why such possibility isn't available in C.

Comment: @willy If two cpp files include your h file and they both call the same template which accesses global variable b, what do you want to happen? Each cpp getting its own global variable or both sharing the same variable?

Comment: @WernerHenze well, both share the same global...accepted answer should do that. But now I wonder if first option is possible too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to put a class around it instead of a namespace, making all functions public static methods of that class and the global variables private static variables.

i.e.:

head.h:

```
class A
{
  public:
    template <typename T> static void MethodA(T const &value)
    {
      //...
    }
    inline static void MethodB(int a, int b)
    {
      // ...
    }

  private:
    static int x;
    static std::string y;
};
```

head.cpp:

```
int A::x = 0;
std::string A::y;
```

**EDIT**:

Another alternate method would be to define the globals as private static variables in a class and make all functions that are allowed to use them friend functions:

head.h:

```
template <typename T> void FunctionA(T const &value);
void FunctionB(int a, int b);

class Vars
{
  friend template <typename T> void FunctionA(T const &value);
  friend FunctionB(int a, int b);

  private:
    static int x;
    static std::string y;
};

template <typename T> void FunctionA(T const &value)
{
  // ...
  // ... A::x ...
  // ...
}
inline void FunctionB(int a, int b)
{
  // ...
  // ... A::y ...
  // ...
}
```

head.cpp:

```
int A::x = 0;
std::string A::y;
```

Comment: yep, even if the simpler and possibly most correct answer was "no", I were asking for a solution and I think you hit the spot

Answer (score 3):

including header files just copies the content of the header file into the including cpp/h file. That means, you cannot really distinguish whether you do something in your header file or in a cpp/h file that includes your header file.

So, variables that are defined in a header file cannot be excluded. If they are in a cpp file and you would like to forbid extern, you could use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
    int variable;
}
```

Best practice, obviously, would be to not use global variables at all. It is considered bad style for several reasons like readability, hard to determine dependencies, difficulties with testing, a really bad chance of extending your software and so on. So, you might reconsider this kind of architecture for your next project if refactoring is not an option here.

Comment: First this creates one variable for each including cpp, not one global variable for them all. Second it does not prevent polluting global namespace, which seems to be what the questioner wants.

Comment: Please read my post carefully. "If they are in a cpp file ..." is clearly said in the sentence before the code fragment. Nothing is included in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
If you declare some variable as **extern** in a header1.h - this variable will be available in any other headers which include header1.h.